# How do I calculate curve integral with given cylinder equation and planes?

Tags: integration

For the vector field $a = [-z^2–2z,-2xz+2y^2,-2xz-2z^3]^T$ and the area $F$ on the cylinder $x^2 + z^2 = 4$ , which is above the ground plane $z = 0$ , in front of the plane $x = 0$ and between the cross plane $y = 0$ and lies to the their parallel plane $y = 2$ , calculate the following integral:
$\int_{F}^{} \! a\cdot dn \, = ?$

Comment: You call the vector field with an $\;a\;$ , which is used in upper case as area, and the area you call it $\;F\;$ , which is a very used letter for vector field...why so? Non-standard notation can be misleading and confusing, in particular when you use exactly the opposite one as in this case!